# Pantalla desajustada en distintos tamaños de pantalla.

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Hola acabo de desarrollar mi aplicación en Xcode 7 con Swift configure las constrains para cada pantalla pero al final cuando la pruebo con diferentes dimensiones en algunas sale bastante desajustada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la primera es con 4 pulgadas Iphone 5 la segunda es con 3.5 pulgadas Iphone 4. Mi consulta hay alguna otra forma de configurar esta pagina mejor que las constraints o ajustar las constrains para que se vean similar en cada tamaña de pantalla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que las constraints no estan bien , al ser la pantalla mas pequeña los items de abajo se ajustan de manera que quepan en la pantalla , para que no pase esto una solución es decirle a todos los items que han de tener el mismo tamaño y aplicarle los margin correctamente.

Answer (score -2):

Buenas no entiendo mucho de desarrollo de aplicaciones pero si de diseño en general y creo que puede ser un problema de poner el tamaño en px y no en % de manera que al cambiar de pantalla dará problemas normalmente cuando es inferior y superior se verá más pequeño ... puede ser algo así? ?

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Mejor es [proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/10737)

Comment: La respuesta es más que válida de hecho vamos acotando el problema

Comment: No. Estás preguntando cosas al usuario a través de tu pregunta: `puede ser algo así? ?` . Eso indica que tienes dudas y si queires realizarle preguntas al autor puedes hacerlo en los comentarios o bien por el chat :). Un saludo!

Comment: Pero no hay para comentar solo responder

Comment: En la pregunta, en la parte de abajo, aparece : `añade un comentario` :) Es lo que te he puesto en mi primer comentario. Pero hasta que no tengas 50 puntos de reputación no podrás hacerlo. Leéto un poco las guías que hay en mi primer comentario y da una respuesta que no requiera clarificación!

Comment: En el desarollo en swift se usan constraints para que se adapte a cualquier pantalla, no con porcentajes, la respuesta no es adecuada